# How to conditionally add classNames to components in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

```html
<div className="fil-container">
    {searchItem == "" ? (
    <MainContent />
    ) : (
    filterBooks.map((filBook) => (
        <Filter
        key={filBook.id}
        imageUrl={filBook.book.imageUrl}
        name={filBook.book.name}
        author={filBook.book.author}
        slug={filBook.book.slug}
        />
    ))
    )}
</div>
```

Here I don't want  `<MainContent />` to apply the `className="fil-container"` styling. How can I apply styles only to `<Filter/>` component, not harming  `<MainContent />` ?

ps: I tried to do this:

```html
{searchItem == "" ? (
    <MainContent />
) : (
    filterBooks.map((filBook) => (
    <div className="fil-container">
        <Filter
        key={filBook.id}
        imageUrl={filBook.book.imageUrl}
        name={filBook.book.name}
        author={filBook.book.author}
        slug={filBook.book.slug}
        />
    </div>
    ))
)}
```

But I want the whole container to have the stylings not just the  component(I mean  components parent component needs the styling, not itself).

Comment: use this library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update like this:

```
<div className={searchItem == "" ? "" :"fil-container"}>
```

Comment: `searchItem && "fil-container"`.